# Shared deployment directory between dockerized wildfly instances

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly

I have 2 dockerized wildfly instances: `wf-1` and `wf-2`.

Deployment volumes indicate on the same location on the physical host.

When I deploy application by deployment scanner, I have marker file `app_name.deployed`.

Is it possible to change name of marker file?

Eg.: name specify that `wf-1` or/and `wf-2` deployed app. Maybe is better solution of share deployment volume ?

Comment: No sure if I undertand your question: but whend deploying you can do: 
deploy --runtime-name=foo.war myapp.war

Comment: I must use deployment scanner

Comment: I guess you are trying to run as a cluster? I tried something similar, but didn't have any luck. Jboss used to have a farm mode, but it didn't make it in the as5 to as7 rewrite